# Plugin not executed in test

Tags: magento2, testing, integration-test

I have a plugin that plugs into the `execute` method of `\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index` and redirects under some condition.

di.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index">
        <plugin sortOrder="1" name="do_stuff_with_cart" type="MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin\CartPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

The Plugin itself:

```php
<?php

namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Plugin;

use MyVendor\MyModule\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render;

class CartPlugin
{
    protected Data $helper;
    protected RedirectInterface $redirect;
    protected ResultFactory $resultFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Data $helper,
        RedirectInterface $redirect,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $resultFactory
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
    }

    public function aroundExecute($subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        if ($this->helper->isEnabled()) {
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setPath('vendor/module/index');

            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

When I access the `/checkout/index/` route locally in my dev environment, everything works as expected. However, this integration test fails:

```php
<?php

namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Test\Integration;

use Magento\TestFramework\TestCase\AbstractController;

class FormTest extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @magentoConfigFixture current_store vendor/module/enabled 1
     */
    public function testShouldRedirectToForm()
    {
        $this->dispatch('checkout/cart/index');

        $this->assertRedirect($this->equalTo('vendor/module/index/'));
    }
}
```

I debugged into my plugin and it looks like the method is never called, even a `die('HERE')` in the `aroundExecute` method does not work. I've tried all the usual stuff (clearing cache, sandbox, generated) already.

When I dump `$this->getResponse()` in the test, it has a status code of 200 but the response content itself is empty.

**EDIT**: I've tried moving the plugin configuration from `etc/frontend/di.xml` to `etc/di.xml` with no success.

Comment: Did you clear the test sandbox after enabling your module?

Comment: @Alex yes, I cleaned it.

Comment: I also faced such issue in 2.4.3 while using preference it wasn't working so I changed it with the plugin that works......try using preference

Comment: @AsadUllah But preference is not a good practice to do.

Comment: the first option is a plugin if that is not working then the preference

Comment: @AsadUllah Ah, now I understand what you mean, sorry. I agree in principle but in my case, this is working with a plugin - just not in the test.

Comment: You should add condition  if ($this->helper->isEnabled()) to the test as well as the plugin will be executed in that condition only.

Answer (score -1):

$request->setPathInfo('checkout/cart/index');

$this->dispatch($request);

Comment: `dispatch` expects a string